# Questions concerning the Fourier analysis of $ nx\ \%\ m$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, galois-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Let $x\ \%\ m$ be the residue of $x$ modulo $m$, i.e.

$$x \equiv x\ \%\ m\pmod{m}$$

The plots of the functions $f_{nm}(x) = nx\ \%\ m$ exhibit characteristic patterns, especially periods of length $1/\operatorname{gcd}(n,m)$. (Look at the zeros of  $f_{nm}(x)$ – there are $\operatorname{gcd}(n,m)$ of them.)

[image]

[image]

---

I found it natural to apply discrete Fourier analysis to $f_{nm}(x) = nx\ \%\ m$, i.e. to determine the coefficients

$\tilde{f}_{nm}( k) = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{x=0}^{m-1}e^{i2\pi k x/m}f_{nm}(x) =  \frac{1}{m}\sum_{x=0}^{m-1}e^{i2\pi k x/m}(nx\ \%\ m)$

I've done this numerically and could reproduce

$f_{nm}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}e^{-i2\pi k x/m}\tilde{f}_{nm}( k) = nx\ \%\ m $

well, so I'm quite confident that I calculated the coefficients correctly.

Plotting the coefficients $\tilde{f}_{nm}( k)$ in the complex plane gives the following pictures for $m = 7,8$. Note that I gave colors to the bars in the $f_{nm}$ plots that indicate, that $f_{nm}$ acts as a permutation and that the numbers $f_{nm}^l(x)$, $1 \leq l \leq l_0$ lie on a permutation cycle of some length $l_0 < m$.

---

### $m = 8$

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### $m = 7$

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

These pictures allow to make some observations, which of course are partly related:

1. $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \tilde{f}_{nm}( k) = 0$
2. $\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{f}_{nm}(0)) = (m - \operatorname{gcd}(n,m))/2$
3. $\operatorname{Im}(\tilde{f}_{nm}(0)) = 0$
4. When $k \neq 0$ then $\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)) = -\operatorname{gcd}(n,m)/2$ for $k \equiv 0 \pmod{\operatorname{gcd}(n,m)}$ and $\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)) = 0$ otherwise.
5. When $m$ is prime then $\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)) = -1/2$ for all $n < m$ and $k\neq 0$.
6. The coefficients $\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)$ always come in conjugate pairs.
7. For $n_1, n_2$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(n_1,m) = 1$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(n_2,m) = 1$ the numbers $\tilde{f}_{n_im}(k)$ are specific permutations of each other.
8. When $m$ is even the number of $k$ with $\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)) < 0$ is $\frac{2}{m - 4}(n - m/2)^2 + 1$
9. When $m$ is prime the number of $k$ with $\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)) < 0$ is $m - 1$.
10. When $n$ and $m$ are coprime the order of the coefficients $\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)$ for $k\neq 0$ is the same as of the numbers $f_{nm}(x)$ for $x \neq 0$.
11. The number of permutation cycles – i.e. different bar colors, including the invisible 1-cycle $(0)$ – is [$\sum_{d|m} \varphi(d)/\omega_d(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3027578/1792) with [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(d)$ and $\omega_d(n)$ the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $n$ modulo $d$. (But that's possibly another story.)

---

Known results that are somehow related to these findings:

- The [sum of the $m$-th roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Summation) is $0$: $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}e^{i2\pi k/m} = 0$.
- Euler's totient function is the [Fourier transform of the greatest common divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Fourier_transform): $\sum_{k=1}^m e^{i2\pi k/m} \cdot \operatorname{gcd}(k,m)  = \varphi(m)$
- The sum $\sum _{d\mid m}\varphi (d)$ [equals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Divisor_sum) $m$.
- The [sum of the roots](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Roots_of_Polynomial) $\rho_k$ of a polynomial $a_mx^m + a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$ equals $-a_{m-1}/a_m$: $\sum _{k = 0}^{m-1}\rho_k = -a_{m-1}/a_m$.
- [Riemann's hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis): The real part of every non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function is $1/2$.
- Concerning permutations (see statement 7) also [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) may be related, which considers permutations of roots as opposed to permutations of Fourier coefficients.

---

Considering that for arbitrary $n,m$ the functions $f_{nm}(x) =nx\ \%\ m$ behave  rather unpredicatable and pseudo-random (like prime numbers do), I guess that proofs of the above statements 5 and 7 (to pick the more tricky ones) may be not elementary or even trivial, especially because there's  no closed formula for $nx\ \%\ m$ that would allow to evaluate the sum $\sum e^{i2\pi k x/m}(nx\ \%\ m)$. But I may be wrong, and elementary proofs do exist. On the other hand, a proof might be as hard as a proof of Riemann's hypothesis. Who knows – I don't?

---

So my question is:

> Is any proof of the above statements known:
>
> **5. When $m$ is prime then $\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)) = -1/2$ for all $n < m$ and $k\neq 0$?**
>
> **7. For $n_1, n_2$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(n_1,m) = 1$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(n_2,m) = 1$ the numbers $\tilde{f}_{n_im}(k)$ are specific permutations of each other.**
>
> **10. When $n$ and $m$ are coprime the order of the coefficients $\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)$ for $k\neq 0$ is the same as of the numbers $f_{nm}(x)$ for $x \neq 0$.**

Comment: Statement 7 is relatively simple; find $a$ invertible (mod m) with inverse $b$ with $a n_1 \cong n_2$; then $\tilde{f}_{n_2 m}(k) = \tilde{f}_{n_1 m}(b k)$. All that's needed is that $\%m$ is periodic and that $f_{n_1 m}$ and $f_{n_2 m}$ can be seen as "dilations" of each other.

Comment: @user44191: Thanks. Am I right, and this is just a proof *idea*? Where and how does the magic occur? Why "then"? (Ah, you edited your comment in the meanwhile. What is a "dilation"?)

Comment: I mean what GH from MO stated at the top of his post: a change of variables via multiplication by an invertible element of $\mathbb{Z}/m$.

Comment: Statements 1 and 5 imply statement 2; statements 1 and 6 imply statement 3; statement 5 is a special case of statement 4; I'm pretty sure statement 8 is false; statement 5 implies statement 9.

Comment: I am not sure about the meaning of statement 10. At any rate, I gave a simple explicit formula for $\tilde f_{nm}(k)$ when $\gcd(n,m)=1$. This should explain many observations.

Comment: @user44191: I am aware of this, that's why I wrote "which of course are partly related". Please prove me that I'm wrong about statement 8, I had a hard time to figure it out.

Comment: @GHfromMO: To see what I mean, please have a carefull look at the pictures. This will show you what I mean (I hope).

Comment: Your statement 8 contradicts statement 5 and what I proved below. For $\gcd(n,m)=1$ and $m\nmid k$ the real part of $\tilde f_{n,m}(k)$ equals $-1/2$.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Thanks for pointing out that you gave a simple explicit formula! That's what I didn't expect - and what I find thrilling, given the quasi-randomness of $nx\ \%\ m$ (at least in some respects). What I try to understand: Why doesn't such "taming randomness" help with Riemann's hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks! My previous comment was wrong: the cotangent value indeed behaves nicely in $k$, but on the other hand $\bar n\bmod{m}$ is pretty random; its distribution is tied with Kloosterman sums.

Comment: I like the way that Riemann Hypothesis is listed under "known results".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\gcd(n,m)=1$, we have by a change of variable $nx\mapsto x$ that
$$\tilde f_{n,m}(k)=\tilde f_{1,m}(\bar n k),$$
where $\bar n\bmod{m}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $n\bmod{m}$. This proves Claim 7 (as user44191 said earlier).

Claim 5 now follows easily, since for $k\not\equiv 0\pmod{m}$ we have
$$\tilde f_{n,m}(k)=\tilde f_{1,m}(\bar n k)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{x=0}^{m-1}e^{2\pi i\bar nk x/m}x=\frac{1}{e^{2\pi i\bar nk/m}-1}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\cot\frac{\pi \bar nk}{m}.$$

Comment: I think you may have forgotten an $i$ somewhere? Also, it may be helpful to note that the equality after the sum uses the fact that $k \neq 0$.

Comment: @user44191: Good catch, I fixed both issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GHfromMO: Thanks for the "simple explicit formula" for $\tilde{f}_{n,m}(k)$! That's what I didn't expect - and what I find thrilling, given the quasi-randomness of $nx\ \%\ m$ (at least in some respects). What I try to understand: Why doesn't such "taming randomness" help with Riemann's hypothesis.

Comment: Just because the Riemann hypothesis is often summarized as saying that the primes "behave randomly" doesn't mean that every random-seeming phenomenon that gets analyzed is related to the Riemann hypothesis. The onus is on someone asserting a relationship with RH to provide some mathematical evidence.

Comment: @HansStricker: I think Greg Martin meant his previous comment for you.

Comment: @GHfromMO: I posted a related question at MSE: [The slope of $nx\ \%\ m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090706/the-slope-of-nx-m). Maybe you want to have a look and possibly give an answer?

Comment: @HansStricker: Sorry, I am not active on MSE. Also, I am very busy these days. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: So just have a look when you find the time;-) I hope you won't regret it.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Another related question (this time at MO again): [Connection between Fourier analysis and Galois theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321903/connection-between-fourier-analysis-and-galois-theory)

Comment: @GregMartin: I took the onus concerning relationship to GT, please have a look: [Connection between Fourier analysis and Galois theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321903/connection-between-fourier-analysis-and-galois-theory)

Answer (score 2):

This is an elementary proof for statement 7:

If $\gcd(n_1, m) = \gcd(n_2, m)$, then there is some $\text{(mod m)}$-invertible $a$ (with inverse $b$) such that $a n_1 \equiv n_2 \text{(mod m)}$ (this statement is surprisingly not immediately easy to prove, but isn't hard with Chinese Remainder Theorem). Then $\tilde{f}_{n_2 m}(k) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{x = 0}^{m - 1} e^{2 \pi i k x/m} (n_2 x \% m)$

$= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{x \in \{0, \dots, m - 1\}} e^{2 \pi i k x/m} (a n_1 x \% m)$

$= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{x' \in \{0, \dots, m - 1\}} e^{2 \pi i k bx'/m} (a n_1 bx' \% m)$
(using the substitution $x \equiv b x' (mod m)$)

$= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{x' \in \{0, \dots, m - 1\}} e^{2 \pi i k bx'/m} (n_1 x' \% m)$

Let $k' = bk$:

$= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{x' \in \{0, \dots, m - 1\}} e^{2 \pi i k' x'/m} (n_1 x' \% m)$

$= \tilde{f}_{n_1 m}(k')$.